# Detect Ethernet adapter(s) - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am using this code to detect network adapters:

`(Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceDescription`

The problem with this code is that it detects all network adapters (including Wi-Fi and virtual adapters by VMware).

I just want to detect the ethernet adapters installed in the device.

Could PowerShell do this at all?

Comment: Get-NetAdapter | where interfacedescription -like "*ethernet*"

Comment: Personally, I would use `Get-NetAdapter | where physicalmediatype -eq 802.3`

Comment: that cmdlet has a `-Physical` switch parameter. that will get rid of the virtual ones ... then you can filter for the physical media type  as mentioned by AdminOfThings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Where-Object {$_.PhysicalMediaType -eq "802.3"}).InterfaceDescription
```

Will get all physical network adapters having PhysicalMediaType 802.3 (Ethernet).

Answer (score 1):

Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -match "Ethernet"}

This will show onboard ethernet adapters as well as docking station/USB Ethernet adapters.